# Nginx Range Request in URL Query Parameters

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm building an HLS/DASH streaming server and today I found out using single big files with range requests is better than many small files - It's what Netflix and YouTube currently doing.

But there is a problem; since I have a different domain for video CDN and the actual player page (eg. netflix.com - nflxvideo.net) CORS gets in and sends an OPTION request with every request. Because the player sends a lot of requests this wastes bytes.

Netflix (which also uses nginx) and YouTube fixed this with sending range in URL or query so browser doesn't send OPTION requests:
`https://xx.nflxvideo.net/range/0-64209238?o=...`

I'm trying to achieve the same thing in Nginx but there isn't any way I could find for 4 hours.
We have files stored in the server so we are using sendfile.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no standard way of doing this that I am aware of. You need to write the code to parse the URL and retunes the bytes indicated.

Comment: I'm currently parsing the URL but I couldn't find a way to pass ranges to try_files or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find how to do this, but for the main goal of not wasting resources with OPTIONS requests, there is `Access-Control-Max-Age` header for caching the OPTIONS requests.

Basically set it to Firefox's maximum of 86400 seconds *(24 hours)* and it's working.

I skipped this header before because it was 10 minutes in Chrome, but apparently, it's increased to 2 hours since Chrome 76. It's more than enough since the average duration of our videos is 100 minutes.

More info about the header is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Max-Age).